# The selector "login-app" did not match any elements while using different component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

I have a component in angular 2 as shown below

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginViewModel } from "../ViewModel/Login.ViewModel";
import { LoginService } from "../Service/Login.Service";
@Component({
    selector: 'login-app',
    templateUrl: 'Account/partialLogin',
    providers: [LoginViewModel, LoginService]
})

export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private loginservicemodel: LoginService, private model: LoginViewModel) {
        this.model.userName = 'erere@ada.com';
        this.model.password = "test anand";

    }

    save(modelValue: LoginViewModel, isValid: boolean) {
        if (isValid) {
            this.loginservicemodel.loginHttpCall();
        }
    }

}
```

**Home.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'Home-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Angular Router</h1>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
      <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class HomeComponent {


}
```

The **appModule.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

    import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";
    import { HomeComponent } from "./Components/home.component";

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'Account/Login', component: LoginComponent }

];


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [LoginComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
    export class AppModule { }
```

**login.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<login-app>looding...</login-app>
```

**partialLogin.cshtml**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<p>THis is test</p>
```

**Routing**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    template: "{*url}",defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

I have use the angular 2 routing as you can see in the appmodule.ts.If I navigate to homepage i,e **Home/Index** I will get an error as **The selector "login-app" did not match any elements** and when I navigate to **Account/Login** I will get an error as **The selector "Home-app" did not match any elements**.I know the the condition on appmodule is not working. How can I make this work. Please anyone can solve this issue

Comment: add more code. show your routing file and module.ts file. there may be problem in your routing config

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you didn't import all your other component in you ngModule file. add them in declaration just like you have imported LoginComponent

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule],
    declarations: [LoginComponent],<-- add all your component here
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I, dont have any component I have a simple html page. While navigating to that page also I am getting the same error. Which doesn't have any angular components. Its just a simple html page

Comment: @SanJaisy but you said "When I navigate to login.cshtml page everythings works" and "other page has different selector" ... according to me we use  selector  for component. and i asked for angular 2 routing file not Asp.net.

Comment: I haven't set routing file for angular js

Comment: San - Please look at angular documentation to add routing:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-config

Comment: can you show plnkr of your code. routing is not required if you have only one component.

Comment: this link will show you basic structure of angular 2 app. http://plnkr.co/edit/bXrxWVkP2MWD8yNDYqVD?p=preview  plz check your structure

Comment: one more thing i am seeing is in your ngModule file import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";  here login.component is in component but its html part is in some account folder "Account/partialLogin" check if your path is correct or not. you may be doing mistake here

Comment: @SanJaisy you need<router-outlet></router-outlet> for loading login component. here is complete working example.. use  it https://plnkr.co/edit/odsZq1pL43HtWcUr0taJ?p=preview

Comment: i suggest you to go through angular 2 basic tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/   and if you want it to correct upload plnkr of your code.  bootstrap in @ngmodule should have only one component which is loaded at start of your app. you have included HomeComponent also. all component should be in declarations part not in bootstrap.Logincomponent selector is Account/Login in your routing file and in component code you have used some other name "login-app". bhai have you seen any links that i have shared with you. plz first learn.

Comment: selector for login component is login-app and I am using a template url to navigate the page. So, the page is Account/partialLogin it is not a selector and I have remove the loginComponent from bootstrap.

Comment: Both are different different page. They are not same page. Whole content load on both the page. So please tell me as per this

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to add route in Angular2:

```
        //Create new app.module.ts file
        import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
        import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


        import { LoginComponent } from './Components/login.Component';

        const appRoutes: Routes = [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
        ];

        export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);



        //Import the above define route in your App module
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
        import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";

        //Import your route file
        import { routing } from './app.routing';

        @NgModule({
            imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule,routing,],
            declarations: [LoginComponent],
            bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It is not working for me ..... Same error. I have updated the code.Please have a look

Comment: I am getting an error Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'

Answer (score 0):

Finally the working code.Call the respective selector in HTML page

**AppModule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent} from "./app.component";

import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./Components/home.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home/Index', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Account/Login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'Home/Index', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent,LoginComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**Home.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'Home-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Angular Router</h1>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
      <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
    </nav>

  `
})

export class HomeComponent {


}
```

**login.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginViewModel } from "../ViewModel/Login.ViewModel";
import { LoginService } from "../Service/Login.Service";
@Component({
    selector: 'login-app',
    templateUrl: 'Account/partialLogin',
    providers: [LoginViewModel, LoginService]
})

export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private loginservicemodel: LoginService, private model: LoginViewModel) {
        this.model.userName = 'erere@ada.com';
        this.model.password = "test anand";

    }

    save(modelValue: LoginViewModel, isValid: boolean) {
        if (isValid) {
            this.loginservicemodel.loginHttpCall();
        }
    }

}
```